# Реализация системы плагинов в приложении

Tags: android, плагин

Делаю проект, и чтобы не загружать его необязательным функционалом, я решил оформить его в виде плагинов. Например, плагин добавляет в файлбраузер несколько опций к файлам и их обработку или, в зависимости от типа операции, выделить название файла каким-либо цветом.

Сразу в голову приходит идея: В главном приложении при каждом значимом событии (например, выделение файла) создаём `broadcast` и вещаем его ресиверам в плагинах. В качестве плагина будет приложение без `intent-filter` в манифесте (без возможности запуска) и с BroadcastReceiver'oм. Понятно, что получить тип произошедшего события будет легко (`intent.getIntExtra("event_type")`). Но как получить дополнительные объекты, например, `View`, привязанный к файлу? Если использовать `Parcel`, то можно получить объект, но изменения, сделанные с объектом в плагине, не отобразятся в главном приложении.

Вопрос: можно ли передать в плагин ссылку на Activity главного приложения, чтобы, изменяя данные в плагине, они автоматически отобразились в главном приложении? Поможет ли использование `WeakReference`/`PhantomReference`?

Comment: Писал о возможном варианте - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726702/use-external-application-fragment-activity-inside-application/21014339#21014339 , у него достаточно много ограничений, но для определенных целей (например, простой UI, логика) он может подойти.